# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND for API key link

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a simple program that uses a javascript library called Webix and its code to show up a map. Please note that I have my API key!

The code I am using is pretty simple from its documentation  https://docs.webix.com/desktop__googlemap.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./openmap.js"></script>

  <title>Open map integration</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sample_div" style='width:600px; height:300px; margin:50px;'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //path from which autoload extra libraries
    webix.codebase = "./";

    webix.ui({
      container: "sample_div",
      key: "[REDACTED]",
      view: "google-map",
      id: "map",
      zoom: 6,
      center: [48.724, 8.215]
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But just appears a blank page and I se people on the comments that for them it works!I go to developer tools and I see this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  js.
I click on js file and it directs me to the link where I took the API key from google and says page doesnt work.

Comment: I see a map then error Google Maps API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

Comment: Have you tried printing `webix` in the console to see if it's loaded correctly?

Comment: your code doesn't actually say "my key here" does it? when i put my google api key there it works perfectly. - this is why you don't mindlessly copy and paste code.

Comment: Hey people I have my API. That is not teh problem. Yes webix works with other things instead of a map

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. No sure that i obtained an API. It appears nothing in my code. How is that possible?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. you put the code in a html file right?

Comment: @user9237345 - yep.. that's normally how it's done

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. and you see the map right? Are you sure? I have one hour realizing what doesnt work in here

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Please what do you think that can be my problem? It takes half a minute to reload and just appears the borders of the map. Everything is blank

Comment: Before reloading the page, open the Developer Tools (F12 in most browsers) and reload the page, check the "Console" tab for errors. Check the "Network" tab for any timed out requests. A waiting time of 30 seconds sounds like you ran into a timeout so especially check the "Network" tab.

Comment: @SaschaM78 yesss I see an error there: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND               js

Comment: @SaschaM78 Maybe it is the API key????????? cause the file that gives the error has the API key in the link but doesnt open. I obtain the API key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce Maybe it is the API key????????? cause the file that gives the error has the API key in the link but doesnt open. I obtain the API key here: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-‌​key – user9237345 . Is this the right way to obtain the key?

Comment: The posted code snippet works for me if I remove the key (it isn't required for SO) and make the external libraries load over `https://` (as SO is now running secure).

Comment: @user9237345 - it works fine.. [look here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Awd0mbcEckxBXzKISHFZ?p=preview).

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the API key. You can see it if you click the "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: But yes I have my API key. You can use another one to try that this is not th error!

Comment: Do you really see the map with your API? And without making any change in my code?

Comment: Yes, just as other users said. Nothing is wrong with your code. Are you trying to run this in your computer/localhost/dev environment?

Comment: No I just have the code in a html file. And I press the option: Open file with Google. Just like any other html file

Comment: And by the way Run code snippet gives an error webix is not defined

Comment: that is very weird. I can see the map ... and now you put the key, i don't get an error: I see the map, without webix error. Are you using an ad-blocker?